# SQL Server not immediately providing all data for tables/queries

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, odbc, connection-string, dao

We recently transitioned a back end to SQL Server (from Access), and are still using an Access front end.

I noticed that some tables or forms will not display the number of records in the navigation bar, like they did when we had an Access back end.  I researched and found an article indicating that SQL Server doesn't automatically load all of the records for linked tables or queries until those specific records are requested (or something like that).  Apparently Access does the same thing, but they have different default settings for how many records trigger them to withhold some of the data.

Our database is pretty small by database standards.  Is there a way to just have SQL Server serve us all of the data all of the time?  We already use views and pass through queries to minimize the amount of data it needs to send across the network.  I don't see us getting a lot of performance out of SQL Server being "smart" about serving us this kind of data.  Our users would rather wait a second to get the data and then be able to navigate their forms quicker on the front end, if that makes sense.  And it would be helpful to see the number of records.

For reference:  We use (I hope I get this terminology right; I'm new to this) a DAO connection with a connection string that looks like the following.  Is there something I can add to the connection string to affect this behavior?  Or some setting in our database?

```
' Define connection string
qdf.Connect = "ODBC;Driver=" & myDriver & ";" & _
              "server=" & myServer & ";" & _
              "database=" & mySQLDB & ";" & _
              "uid=" & myuid & ";" & _
              "Pwd=" & mypwd & ";"
```

Comment: Doing such specific things unfortunately is limited to forms. For a form in datasheet view (which looks like a query), I could show you how to do it

Comment: Some questions first: a) your application serves multiple users in each moment of time or it is used by single user mostly? b) 'all data' - you mean only record counts or you can describe which rows are not returned by SqlServer?

Comment: Answers: (a) Serves many (~50) users, although probably not more than ~20 at a time.  (b) I'm not sure what data might or might not be loaded, although some of the web pages I researched suggested that not all of the data was loaded.  Our main issue is the record count, but I just meant that if SQL Server is doing this to improve performance, we don't care much about performance here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to initialize the entire recordset on loading a form, you can do the following:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Me.RecordSet.MoveLast
    Me.RecordSet.MoveFirst
End Sub
```